# Java getMethod "class not found"

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have an application that needs to dynamically load some adapters.  Some of those adapters are compiled into the application while some are supplied at runtime.  Once I have an adapter, I want to call the adapt(OrderToolRequest,Object) method on it.

My problem is that I can get this to work when the class is in the application.  However, for third-party adapters I can load a runtime-supplied class dynamically but I can't figure out how to call the method.  I get "class not found" errors on OrderToolResponse.  I've tried to do this by having all adapters implement an interface and casting, and by simply using reflection to get the method.

I'm assuming this is somehow related to different class loaders, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to solve the problem.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

In the following code, everything works fine until the call to getMethod().  This succeeds if we found the class in the application.  It throws an Error of class not found if the class was loaded by the URLClassLoader

```
Class<?> cls = null;

try
{
    // #1
    cls = Class.forName( adapterName );
}
catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
{
    File file = new File( "Adapters" );
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{ url };

    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader( urls );
    try
    {
        // #2
        cls = loader.loadClass( adapterName );
    }
    finally 
    {
        loader.close();
    }
}

Constructor<?> constructor = cls.getConstructor();
Object instance = constructor.newInstance();

// #3 THE PROBLEM OCCURS HERE.  SUCCEEDS IF LOADED BY #1, BUT FAILS IF LOADED
// BY #2.
Method adaptMethod = cls.getMethod( "adapt", OrderToolRequest.class, Object.class );

...invoke the method, etc.
```

**EDIT to explain more fully**

If the class is loaded by the statement Class.forName( adapterName ), then there is no problem.

If the class is loaded by loader.loadClass( adapterName ), then there is a problem.

If I alter the code to read:

```
Method adaptMethod = null;
try
{
    adaptMethod = cls.getMethod( "adapt", OrderToolRequest.class, Object.class );
}
catch ( Error e )
{
    log.error( "Didn't work" );
}
```

and set a breakpoint on the logging statement, then:

- e.cause = "ClassNotFoundException"
- e.detailMessage =
  "com/ca/eai/model/canonical/OrderToolResponse"

**Edit #2 stack trace.  I had to truncate as more than 30,000 characters**

You'll see a NoClassDefFoundError caused by a ClassNotFoundException.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ca/eai/model/canonical/OrderToolResponse
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at com.ca.eai.esb.transformer.orchestration.AdapterInvokingTransformer.findAdapter(AdapterInvokingTransformer.java:73)
    at com.ca.eai.esb.transformer.orchestration.AdapterInvokingTransformer.transformMessage(AdapterInvokingTransformer.java:106)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:145)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:93)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1455)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1363)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1341)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1333)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.process(AbstractTransformer.java:123)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:312)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:302)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:202)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$1.process(AbstractPipeline.java:112)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$1.process(Flow.java:74)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$1.process(Flow.java:69)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:63)
    at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.process(Flow.java:68)
...SOME STUFF REMOVED HERE...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ca.eai.model.canonical.OrderToolResponse
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 260 more
```

Comment: How does your compiler know what OrderToolRequest is?  Is it in the build file?

Comment: It's in a jar that's in the classpath brought in through a Maven dependency.

Comment: How can [Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) throw a class not found exception?

Comment: @A4L: If the parameter types are not found.

Comment: @Tad How come? [ClassNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is a checked exception and should apear in the throws clause of the method `Class#getMethod` whicht it does not, besides of that you are passing as parameters `OrderToolRequest.class` and `Object.class` and not some dynamically loaded class, so the classes passed are known at compile time, and it if works with classes loaded by #1 then this shows that those parameters are already part of your assemby.

Comment: @A4L: If I knew how come, I probably wouldn't have this problem.  The fact remains that the class loads and instantiates (no exception on newInstance) but an Error is being thrown by the call to getMethod when the class is loaded via URL loader, but not being thrown when the class is loaded via forName().  When the Error is examined, its root cause is a ClassNotFound exception with the OrderToolRequest class listed as the detail.  I would assume that the exception doesn't appear in the throws clause of the getMethod method because it's not being thrown by the method, but by the invoking code.

Comment: Class#getMethod throws NoSuchMethodException, NullPointerException, and SecurityException. It does not throw ClassNotFoundException. You, or the debugger, must be confused. Can you share an exception stacktrace (e.printStackTrace()) ?

Comment: @Ali C: note that I didn't say it was throwing an exception; I said it was throwing an error.  Nonetheless, I've edited the post to contain the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Do not close the loader. Javadoc:

> Closes this URLClassLoader, so that it can no longer be used to load
>   new classes or resources that are defined by this loader.

Comment: `URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());` would have been my next idea. Providing the cls class not only with the URLClassLoader, but the system class loader too. Or `getClass.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: However, that kind of thinking did lead me to a workaround.  By chaning to URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader( urls, OrderToolResponse.class.getClassLoader() ); I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the class or method we're trying to retrieve, but looking at the exception cause you provided, I don't believe [Class#getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) is throwing the ClassNotFoundException.

Instead, the target method "adapt" likely has a return type of com.ca.eai.model.canonical.OrderToolResponse and that class is not in the Classpath.

Comment: Hmmm, that class is in the same jar as OrderToolRequest.  I can insert the line "OrderToolResponse response = new OrderToolResponse();" into my code in this function and it works perfectly.  Is this something to do with the fact that the URLClassLoader doesn't have that jar in one of its paths?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to try, but with the way you have it defined, URLClassLoader should delegate to the default classloader and that should be able find things in the classpath. Had you instantiated URLClassLoader using new URLClassLoader(urls, null), it wouldn't delegate then I would expect this behavior...

Comment: URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader( urls, OrderToolResponse.class.getClassLoader() ); worked.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the URL loader as follows solves my problem.

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader( urls, OrderToolResponse.class.getClassLoader() );
```

I'm still not sure why the default class loader isn't working.